# The mysql.createpool function is synchronous and asynchronous?

Tags: mysql, node.js

this my code.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var pool  = mysql.createPool({
    Host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'root',
    database : 'guess'
});
```

The mysql.createpool function is synchronous and asynchronous ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the 'mysql' module in require function was installed by 'npm install mysql',
then mysql.createPool function is synchronous.

refer to below.(from https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#connection-options)
you can use pool immediately.(not in callback and not in then())

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 10,
  host            : 'example.org',
  user            : 'bob',
  password        : 'secret',
  database        : 'my_db'
});

pool.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The function

```
mysql.createPool(connectionOptions)
```

return a Bluebird `Promise` that resolves to a pool object, so it's asynchronous.

Watch here for more information: https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql